# what is the obstacle.cpp file in teb_local_planner for?

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

correct me if im wrong . but is the obtacle.cpp file for obstacle msgs for dynamic obstacles

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242236/what-is-the-obstacle.cpp-file-in-teb_local_planner-for?/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-11-16**:
hey, please indicate whether your questions is answered or not in order to clean up the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the obstacle.cpp file along with its header defines the obstacle interface and particular implementations (point, line, polygon obstacles) for consideration in the teb_local_planner optimization problem.
Although the obstacle class contains member fields for velocities, the teb_local_planner does not support actual dynamic obstacles yet. I am going to edit this answer as soon as it is supported.

EDIT: dynamic obstacles are now supported. Please check the tutorials ;-)

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0